# regex_extract in Hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I have string column and i want the data after first semicolon

Column data:    Options;list:direct & ACFs:Sharemarket

I want the output  as
list:direct & ACFs:Sharemarket

I have tried the option
select (regexp_extract(property,'^(?:([^;]*)\;?){2}',1)) results the output as list:direct &amp
How can populate complete string after first semi colon like my output as
list:direct & ACFs:Sharemarket

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select regexp_extract('Options;list;direct & ACFs:Sharemarket','\\;(.*)$')
```